# saveTextAsFile is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save  to file but getting error 'saveTextAsFile is not defined' see below

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='SaveTextAsFile.js'></script>

<textarea id="inputTextToSave" style="width:512px;height:256px"></textarea>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have that function saveTextAsFile() in file SaveTextAsFile.js in the same directory as html:

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine; I think it's your .js file that's not reachable. Are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: Can you confirm that `SaveTextAsFile.js` is being loaded? On some servers, filename casing matters.

Comment: Is that the entire `.js` file? It's not wrapped in any kind of `ready()` handler or other function?

Comment: Should work (tested if the script is embedded with HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/fgfmkx99/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a slash to the beginning of your script tag src to make it absolute to your host, otherwise, if you are in an url say `"localhost/foo/bar/"`, the 
browser will try to load the file from `"localhost/foo/bar/SaveTextAsFile.js"`, if you add the slash, it will try to load it from `"localhost/SaveTextAsFile.js"`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/SaveTextAsFile.js'></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that both the HTML and JS are *in* the web site's root? OP already stated that the JS file is in the same folder as the HTML. If so, the slash isn't necessary, and might in fact be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure? did you test it? are you sure OP is loading the page from the root host?

Comment: just add a script/image tag to a page and test it. Check the network tab in the console on both cases, with a slash and without a slash. I've test it and had similar issues a long ago and solve them with this.